# Chrome: disable pre-render of hash change

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, prefetch

We're developing a web application that handles state change via change of the hash of the page (e.g. `example.com/#/page1`).

Lately, I've been running into an issue with Google Chrome, when the prefetch option is enabled ("Predict network actions to improve page load performance"). Among the different routes, we have `#/logout` that performs the logout.
In the "normal" state, I'm on the page `example.com/#/` (the main page), and as I start typing "l" after that (`example.com/#/l`), Chrome autocompletes with `logout`. However, not only it does autocomplete, but it also calls the "haschange" event, so the client is sending a request to log out to the server... Even just by typing a `l`!

This behaviour is not only unexpected, but it's also dangerous. Aside from unchecking "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" in the settings page (which is on by default), is there a way to prevent Chrome to do this?

**EDIT**

A small new "discovery". Actually, Chrome is not firing the "hashchange" event, as a console.log in the event handler is not being executed. Chrome learnt that, when visiting the `#/logout` page, a request to the server (`GET /auth/destroy`) is called, and so it's firing it by itself! What can we do to stop this?

Comment: Why are you still using hashchange events? Are you still supporting old IE versions?

Comment: @epascarello Not because of IE support, but for other reasons that are beyond the scope of the question. GMail itself uses hashchange events, eventually.

Comment: Apparently, enabling HTTPS disables the prefetching (per https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender
 ). However, it would be nice to know if there are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. This is not really a solution, but rather a workaround.

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender), prendering is disabled in certain situations: with POST requests (not an option in our case) and when the resources are served via HTTPS.
Since we were already going to enable HTTPS in the production environment, we just enabled it in the development one as well and the issue disappeared. However, I still feel like this is more of a workaround than a real solution.

Comment: It seems that POST requests are being fired even in prerender now. I don't have any sources, but my auth system is able to refresh my tokens via a POST request even while ```document.visibilityState === "prerender"```. (Using Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m)